# Windows phone emulator in windows 8.1 pro (64-bit)

Tags: windows-phone-8-emulator, hyperthreading

I am trying to enable hyper thread on my pc windows 8.1 pro (64-bit). It is core i3 h61m-ds2 gigabyte motherboard. I have installed coreinfo.exe from there i have seen that my pc have hyper thread facility. 
I follow all the step describe here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx#coreinfo . But when i restart my pc after turning on the hyper option then when i turn on the pc it shows me that it fails to update all my changes .And after that when i try to run the emulator it again ask me to turn on the hyper v feature. I again did this and again it asked me to restart ... did it again ... and again the same thing appears.

P.S.  I try to go to bios setup when the pc starts by pressing del key. In there i don't find most of the bios feature. Is there any other way to go to the advanced bios setting or may be any other bios setting .

Comment: I hope you are using VS express for desktop. If so please update it. Visual Studio 2012 Update 4. It gives 8.1 support. Thanks

Comment: So already updated that though it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There were some issues related to hyper V and Gigabyte motherboard. Make sure you have updated the BIOS/Firmware of the computer to the latest supported release by GIGABYTE.